# Python class and __iter__

Tags: python, class, iteration

What are the benefits of using the `__iter__` function in a Python class?

In the code below I am just setting up two simple classes. The first class takes in a list as an argument, and I am able to loop over this list without using the `__iter__` function. The second bit of code uses the `__iter__` function to loop over a list.

What is the benefit of using `__iter__` when there are already ways of looping over stuff in a class?

```
EG 1: no __iter__


class test_class:
    def __init__(self, list):
        self.container_list = list

    def print (self):
        a = self.container_list
        return a

test_list = test_class([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

x = test_class.print(test_list)

for i in x:
    print (i)



EG 2: yes __iter__

class list_using_iter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = [1,2,3,4]
        self.index = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index == len(self.list):
            raise StopIteration
        return self.list [self.index]

r = list_using_iter()
itr = iter(r)

print(next(itr))
print(next(itr))
print(next(itr))
print(next(itr))

print(next(itr)) # Raises the exception!
```

Comment: In the first case you are not iterating over the `test_class` object itself, you are iterating over what is returned by the  `test_class.print` function (which is a list).  Try something like: `for i in test_class([1,2,3,4]): print(i)` and see what happens.

Comment: `__iter__` isn't for looping over stuff *inside the class*, it is for making the objects that are instances of the class *iterable*.

Comment: Note, also, you are simply re-implementing `list_iterator` in your `list_using_iter` class, which isn't very useful. I.e., it is equivalent to simply `itr = iter([1,2,3,4])`

Comment: thanks for the comments. So the list in EG 1 is iterable anyway since it is a list. And I have missed the point of the __iter__ function because it is used to iterate over instances of a class rather than attributes of a method that is inside a class ( which is what I have done in EG 1 with the list ) . What would it look like to loop over instances of a class? I know the __init__ method constructs instances of a class. If I construct multiple instances of a class, then how are these instances stored and accessed by python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is not iterable, but contains an attribute that is. Your second example is iterable, but you iterate simply by "following" another iterable. Here's an example of a iterable that does more work itself:

```
import itertools

class Fibs:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __iter__(self):
        a = self.a
        b = self.b
        while True:
            yield a
            a, b = b, a + b

real_fibs = Fibs(0,1)

for i in itertools.islice(real_fibs, 10):
    print(i)
```

`Fibs.__iter__` isn't simply regurgitating values obtained from some other value's `__iter__` method; it is computing and yielding new values on demand.

---

Actually, the preceding is an example of a class that knows how to create its own iterator, rather than having each object *be* iterable. Here's a version that defines `next` itself.

```
class Fibs:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        rv = self.a
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        return rv
```

Comment: thank you very much for the examples, they have made things so much clearer now :)

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the looping works because of `__iter__`.  In your first example, your print function returns a loop.
The implementation of the `for` keyword will call `__iter__` (or the corresponding slot within the C implementation since the code involved is in the C interpreter) in order to loop over the list.

In your second example you could have written

```
for elt in r:
    print(elt)
```

which would have internally called `__iter__` to implement the for loop.

In general you tend to use `for` rather than `iter` and `next` directly.  The cases where you use `iter` and `next` directly are when you're producing a callback function that will produce an iterator or when you're defining one iterator in terms of another.

In terms of when should you write your own `__iter__` or return some object that does its own iteration, that all depends on what functionality you want.  For example, your first class is more powerful because two people can be iterating the list at the same time.  In your second class, because you store the index in the class itself, only one person can successfully use the iterator at a time.
However, if you had complex enough behavior, the second approach where you define your own `__iter__` might make sense.

Comment: thanks for the answer Sam :)  looks like the __iter__ function is used automatically to do iteration with some python objects/commands. No need for calling it manually, unless I want to add iteration functionality to objects that do not have iteration builtin. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: It is.  If this answers has answered your question, please accept it.